# How to install Ktechlab on Kubuntu 12.10 64-bits

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, kubuntu

I try to install Ktechlab on my Kubuntu 12.10 64-bits.  It had a lot of problem.  It missed a lot of dependencies.  I try to download them, but they still missed alot of other.  What is the good faster way to install this application.

Comment: have you tried with sudo apt-get install -f ?

Comment: Check this question here on Ask Ubuntu: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/8698)

Answer (score 0):

With this script you can solved it:

http://elpuig.xeill.net/Members/rborrell/ktechlab-in-ubuntu